# Access query for one bib with multiple holdings

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using the Access query below to bring up bib records that have holding locations in 'stacks' and 'lebh shomea library'. however, the 'and' operator in Access brought up no records and the 'or' operator brings up everything that has a location of 'stacks' and everything that has a location of 'lebh shomea library'. I need records that have (ONLY) holdings for both locations.

```
SELECT BIB_TEXT.BIB_ID,
       BIB_TEXT.AUTHOR,
       BIB_TEXT.TITLE_BRIEF,
       BIB_TEXT.PUBLISHER_DATE,
       BIB_VW.MFHD_LOCATION
FROM ((((BIB_TEXT
         INNER JOIN BIB_VW ON BIB_TEXT.BIB_ID = BIB_VW.BIB_ID)
        INNER JOIN MFHD_MASTER ON BIB_VW.MFHD_ID = MFHD_MASTER.MFHD_ID)
       INNER JOIN MFHD_HISTORY ON MFHD_MASTER.MFHD_ID = MFHD_HISTORY.MFHD_ID)
      INNER JOIN MFHD_ITEM ON MFHD_MASTER.MFHD_ID = MFHD_ITEM.MFHD_ID)
INNER JOIN BIB_MFHD ON BIB_TEXT.BIB_ID = BIB_MFHD.BIB_ID
WHERE (((BIB_VW.MFHD_LOCATION)="STACKS"
        OR (BIB_VW.MFHD_LOCATION)="LEBH SHOMEA LIBRARY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that there is a one-to-many relationship between records in `BIB_TEXT` and `BIB_VW`.  If that is the case, you would need to make a query on `BIB_VW`:

```
SELECT BIB_ID 
FROM BIB_VW 
WHERE MFHD_LOCATION="STACKS" OR MFHD_LOCATION="LEBH SHOMEA LIBRARY" 
GROUP BY BIB_ID 
HAVING COUNT(MFHD_LOCATION) = 2
```

... and replace `BIB_VW` in your original query with references to this subquery, removing the original query's `WHERE` clause.